# How do I print session values?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I am setting up a new online pizza ordering website and want to print out the user's orders including the price on the Checkoutpage.php. How do I achieve this using sessions?

I have tried using sessions, php, get and post.

**OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Online Pizza Ordering Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Online Pizza Ordering Page</h1>
  <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=supreme">
    <img src="supreme.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Supreme"         
    alt="Supreme">
  </a>
  <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=meatlover">
    <img src="meatlover.jpg" width="82" height="86" 
    title="Meatlover" alt="Meatlover">
  </a>
  <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=hawaii">
    <img src="hawaii.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Hawaii" 
    alt="Hawaii">
  </a>
  <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=fourseasons">
    <img src="fourseasons.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Four 
    Seasons" alt="Four Seasons">
  </a>
  <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php?pizza=vege">
    <img src="vege.jpg" width="82" height="86" title="Vege" 
    alt="Vege">
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Detailedsauceandquantitypage.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Detailed sauce and quantity page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Detailed sauce and quantity page</h1>
    <form action="ShoppingCartpage.php" method="POST">
       <!-- set form value to retrieve and pass the selected pizza to
        the cart -->
        <input type="hidden" name="pizza" value="<?php echo         
        htmlspecialchars($_GET['pizza'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); ?>">
        <img src="bbq.jpg" alt="BBQ">
        <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
        <input type="number" name="bbqPizza" min="0" max="100" 
        value="0">
        <br>
        <img src="tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato">
        <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
        <input type="number" name="tomatoPizza" min="0" max="100" 
        value="0"> 
        <br>
        <img src="salsa.jpg" alt="Salsa">
        <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
        <input type="number" name="salsaPizza" min="0" max="100" 
        value="0"> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="submit">
        <br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ShoppingCartpage.php**

```
<?php 

if (!session_id()) {
            //initialize the session if it is not already
  session_start();
}
if (!array_key_exists('pizzas', $_SESSION)) {
            //create initial storage of all pizzas
  $_SESSION['pizzas'] = [];
}
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
  if (!array_key_exists('pizza', $_POST)) {
               //a pizza was not selected, redirect the user back to the first         
    page.
  }
            //determine sauce type quantities
  foreach(['bbqPizza', 'tomatoPizza', 'salsaPizza'] as $sauce) {
                //retrieve the quantity as an integer value
    if ($qty = filter_var($_POST[$sauce], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                    //add to the order only those that were selected
                    //use a placeholder to store the quantity of sauce and         
      pizza
      $key = $_POST['pizza'] . '_' . $sauce;
      if (!array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION['pizzas'])) {
        $_SESSION['pizzas'][$key] = [
          'pizza' => $_POST['pizza'],
          'sauce' => $sauce,
          'qty' => 0
        ];
      }
                    //increment the quantity of the pizza and sauce
      $_SESSION['pizzas'][$key]['qty'] += $qty;
    }
  }
}
if (empty($_SESSION['pizzas'])) {
           //no pizzas were added redirect to the first page.
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Shopping Cart page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ol>   
    <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['pizzas'])) { 
      foreach($_SESSION['pizzas'] as $pie) { ?>
        <li>
          <?php printf('%s %s pizzas with %s sauce', $pie['qty'],         
          $pie['pizza'], $pie['sauce']); ?>
        </li>
      <?php }
    } ?>
  </ol>
  <br>
  <a href="OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html">Add more pizzas to cart</a>
  <a href="Checkoutpage.html">Go to checkout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Checkoutpage.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Checkout page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Checkout page</h1>
  <form action="Confirmationpage.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input type="number" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">        
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected results is to display all the user's orders and their individual prices and then display a total price, on the Checkoutpage.php. The actual result is nothing is displayed.

Comment: Did you try something like print_r($_SESSION) to see what you have inside?

Comment: "_The actual result is nothing is displayed._" You're actually not outputting anything on your `Checkoutpage.php`, what did you expect? Start a session in `Checkoutpage.php` and `print_r($_SESSION)` like MilanG said to see what your session contains.

Comment: Oh! I didn't think about that.

Comment: Not working, in fact if I refresh the page all the orders stay. I need to make the orders delete once the page refreshes. Otherwise if the teacher refreshes the page and tests another set of pizzas then he will see his old orders still there.